# Have I destroyed my device

Tags: power-supply, repair

I have connected a wrong adapter to my [Inforce 6410](http://www.inforcecomputing.com/product/moreinfo/ifc6410.html) device. It takes 5V but I have accidentally connected a 19V adapter. The board got heat up and I saw some smoke, now when I connect the 5V adapter, the boards gets heat up a lot and does not boot up.

What might have I destroyed, and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: Something with that high a level of integration is unlikely to be repairable.

Comment: Specifically which part gets hot?  The main controller/RAM or just the voltage regulator?  If the regulator is the only part that gets warm, you might be able to replace it.  However, if other parts are heating up, then it is likely not repairable.  I once put 12V into an FPGA board that wanted 5V.  Fortunately, the only part that got damaged was a switching regulator controller.  After swapping that out (yay free samples) it worked perfectly.

Comment: Everything is getting hot, the whole board is getting very hot.

Comment: If everything is getting hot, then you have an expensive coaster.  All of the components have likely seen voltages far in excess of their design specification and as a result have entered avalanche breakdown and/or latchup and essentially self-destructed.  The damaged remains can pass very significant leakage current, resulting in all of the components heating up.  It would be cheaper and easier to buy a new board than to replace all of the parts.

Comment: Since the board is supplied with 5v I can only assume that if feeds that 5v to several sections directly and uses some regulators to lower it to 3,3v or lower to feed specific low voltage sections. I doubt that the complete board is behind a regulator so the damage is probably unrepairable.

Comment: First Check Voltage regulators and capacitors near it.

Comment: checked, no sign on damage.

Comment: repair advice is generally off-topic, simply because we all end up just guessing wildly at what could be wrong here ...

Answer (score 2):

This might be repairable,

First you have to locate where the heat is produced when you plug your 5V adapter (or better: a lab power supply with current limiting features)

If the heat is produced close to the power connector, it's likely that it's a protection diode or a voltage regulator (linear or switching) that is dead.

If smokes got out, inspect visually that region. The broken package is likely to be damaged and this might be noticeable. This will give you a clue of what happens, and thus what you have to do to repair.

Once you found what is destroyed, you could take proper action to detect if something else is broken and then replace the broken parts. I can't say much about this part because it's dependent on the kind of failure you have. There are not magical repairing procedures that can be applied to any kind of failure.

You also have to check that you have the proper equipment to repair the board. If the broken part is a small SMD chip, you have to have access to the proper soldering iron. If the broken part is a BGA... then forget it..